# Is there any way I can make this code faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, search, time

I'm writing this search engine in python for a list of recipes and it's supposed to run at a certain speed per search 0.1 seconds max. I've been struggling to achieve this speed with my code. I've been getting 0.4 on average. I wanted to know if you have any idea on how to make this code faster. I've try so many things but I know that the loop is the one that's making it way slower. If I can improve it with mostly python and not adding that many modules.

I've already made it faster on the other parts of the code 0.005 avg. but in this part with big amount of recipes it gets pretty slow.

```
def countTokens(token):
    token = str(token).lower()

    #make digits an punctuations white spaces
    tokens = token.translate(token.maketrans(digits + punctuation,\
            " "*len(digits + punctuation))) 

    return tokens.split(" ")

def normalOrder(recipes, queries):
    for r in recipes:
        k = r.keys()  
        parts, scores = [[],[],[],[]], 0
        parts[0] = countTokens(r["title"])
        parts[1] = countTokens(r["categories"]) if "categories" in k else []
        parts[2] = countTokens(r["ingredients"]) if "ingredients" in k else []
        parts[3] = countTokens(r["directions"]) if "directions" in k else []
        for q in queries:
            scores += 8 * parts[0].count(q) + 4 * parts[1].count(q) + 2 * parts[2].count(q) + 1 * parts[3].count(q)

        r["score"] = scores + r["rating"] if "rating" in k else 0
    return recipes
```

On a little bit of context I need to sum the amount of occurrences of a queries in the four descriptor above only if the have it that's why I have the if's.

Comment: Can you show some sample data ?

Comment: You check whether a key is in the dictionary and then retrieve the value if it exists. This requires 2 lookups. You can use [**`dict.get`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and provide a default. This will result in only one lookup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed a few points:

- Each time you're calling `countTokens`, you are generating the same translation table again (the `maketrans` call). I guess this will not be optimized away, so you're probably losing performance there.
- `tokens.split(" ")` creates a list of all words in the string, which is rather expensive, e.g. when the string is 100.000 words. You don't need that.
- Overall, it looks like you're simply trying to count how often a word is contained in a string. Using [`string.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), you could count the occurences with much
  less overhead.

If you apply that, you don't need the `countTokens` function anymore, and with a little bit of refactoring end up with this:

```
def normalOrder(recipes, queries):
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe["score"] = recipe.get("rating", 0)

        for query in queries:
            recipe["score"] += (
                8 * recipe["title"].lower().count(query)
                + 4 * recipe["categories"].lower().count(query)
                + 2 * recipe["ingredients"].lower().count(query)
                + 1 * recipe["directions"].lower().count(query)
            )

    return recipes
```

Does this work for you -- and is it fast enough?

Edit: In your original code, you wrapped access to `recipe["title"]` and the other strings in another `str()` call. I guess they already are string? If they are not, you need to add that here.

---

Edit2: You stated in the comments that punctuation is a problem. As I said in the comments, I think you don't need to worry about that, since the `count` calls will only care about punctuation characters if both the query word and the recipe text contain one, then the count call will only count the occurences where surrounding punctuation matches what is queried. Take a look at these examples:

```
>>> "Some text, that...".count("text")
1
>>> "Some text, that...".count("text.")
0
>>> "Some text, that...".count("text,")
1
```

If you want this to behave differently, you could do something like you are doing in your original question: Create a translation table and apply that.
Keep in mind that applying this translation to the recipe texts (as you did in your question) does not make much sense, since then, any query word that contains punctuation just never matches. This could be done much easier by just ignoring all query word that contain punctuation.
You would probably want to do the translation on the query term, so that if someone enters "potato,", you find all occurences of "potato". This would look like this:

```
def normalOrder(recipes, queries):
    translation_table = str.maketrans(digits + punctuation, " " * len(digits + punctuation))
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe["score"] = recipe.get("rating", 0)

        for query in queries:
            replaced_query = query.translate(translation_table)
            recipe["score"] += (
                8 * recipe["title"].lower().count(replaced_query)
                + 4 * recipe["categories"].lower().count(replaced_query)
                + 2 * recipe["ingredients"].lower().count(replaced_query)
                + 1 * recipe["directions"].lower().count(replaced_query)
            )

    return recipes
```

---

Edit3: In the comments, you stated that you want a search for ["honey", "lemon"] to match "honey-lemon", but that you do not want "butter" to match "butterfingers". For this, your initial approach is probably the best solution, but keep in mind that searching for a singular form "potato" will not match the plural form ("potatoes") or any other derived form anymore.

```
def normalOrder(recipes, queries):
    transtab = str.maketrans(digits + punctuation, " " * len(digits + punctuation))
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe["score"] = recipe.get("rating", 0)

        title_words = recipe["title"].lower().translate(transtab).split()
        category_words = recipe["categories"].lower().translate(transtab).split()
        ingredient_words = recipe["ingredients"].lower().translate(transtab).split()
        direction_words = recipe["directions"].lower().translate(transtab).split()

        for query in queries:
            recipe["score"] += (
                8 * title_words.count(query)
                + 4 * category_words.count(query)
                + 2 * ingredient_words.count(query)
                + 1 * direction_words.count(query)
            )

    return recipes
```

If you invoke this function more often with the same recipies, you can get more performance out of it by storing the results of `.lower().translate().split()` in the recipies, then you don't need to recreate that list in every invocation.

Depending on your input data (how many queries to you have on average?), it might also make sense to just go though the `split()` result once and just sum up the count of each word. This would make a look up for a single word much fast and can also be kept between function invocations, but it's more expensive to build:

```
from collections import Counter

transtab = str.maketrans(digits + punctuation, " " * len(digits + punctuation))

def counterFromString(string):
    words = string.lower().translate(transtab).split()
    return Counter(words)

def normalOrder(recipes, queries):
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe["score"] = recipe.get("rating", 0)

        title_counter = counterFromString(recipe["title"])
        category_counter = counterFromString(recipe["categories"])
        ingredient_counter = counterFromString(recipe["ingredients"])
        direction_counter = counterFromString(recipe["directions"])

        for query in queries:
            recipe["score"] += (
                8 * title_counter[query]
                + 4 * category_counter[query]
                + 2 * ingredient_counter[query]
                + 1 * direction_counter[query]
            )

    return recipes
```

Edit4: I've replaced the defaultdict with a Counter -- wasn't aware that class existed.

Comment: I need to make sure that the words don't have numbers or punctuations first. how can I go around that while keeping this solution

Comment: If the queries do not contain any punctuation, then punctuation in the recipe texts is not a problem -- it will simply not be counted: `"Cut the potatoes, broccoli and peppers".count("potato")` will return 1.

So this is only an issue if a query contains punctuation and a recipe text also contains punctuation. Could you provide an example and explain what should be done in this case? A solution could be to remove all punctuation characters using the approach you have in your question, just make sure you're only generating the translation table once.

Comment: I added a more in-depth explanation of my thoughts to the answer, check that out.

Comment: in the case of lemon-honey when my queries are lemon and honey. wouldn't that ignore on the words?

Comment: Nope, `"lemon-honey".count("lemon")` is 1, and `"lemon-honey".count("honey")` is also 1. Both queries will be found and matched.

`str.count()` in python is not based on words, it's based on character sequences. It does not need the word you are searching for to be surrounded by spaces. If you do `"psychotherapist".count("other")` it will return 1, because the string contains these characters in that order.

Comment: I have this very specific case in categories where words are saved in a list and when I look for peanut butter it should count as 1 per each but it seems like is not counting them.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? If I run this:
`normalOrder([{"title": "peanut-butter & jelly sandwich", "categories": "peanut, butter", "ingredients": "peanut-butter, jelly, bread", "directions": "",}], ["peanut", "butter"])`
I get a recipe with score 28 - 8 for "peanut" in title, 8 for "butter" in title, 4 for "peanut" in categories, 4 for "butter" in categories, 2 for "peanut" in ingredients, 2 for "butter" in ingredients.

Comment: the issue is that is matching Butterfingers when I'm looking for butter but it shouldn't match those words. You are right about the punctuations but how would I would avoid getting non single match words

Comment: that's why I needed the split

Comment: I updated the answer, see Edit3. If this implementation gives the right results, but is not enough performance wise, you need to tell us a little more about the input data, preferable give some raw input data to us for queries that are slow. Building up an inverted index might make sense. As I wrote in the answer, make sure to cache the split result if you're calling the `normalOrder` more than once for the same recipies.

Comment: I have invert indexing implemented already but I'm not sure how to use it for this search. The data I'm using is a json file. It only has one title and it can have multiple categories, multiple instructions and multiple directions or none of those threes and it always has a tutor

Comment: I have less than 5 queries per average

Comment: So the last code snipped I posted works but is still not fast enough? Can you upload the json file somewhere and link it here so we can try to find a more optimized solution for your data?

Comment: Heyyy!! When you mentioned the reverse index I thought how can I make that part better... And improving the reserve index made the code faster. I'll add it to the question if someone can get some help in the future. (not the pretties solution but definitely faster). Thank for the help

Comment: It wasn't possible to actually improve this code since I had to run it so many times

Answer (score 1):

First you can use `get` instead of if condition.

```py
def countTokens(token): 
     if token is None:
         return []
    token = str(token).lower() #make digits an punctuations white spaces
    tokens = token.translate(token.maketrans(digits + punctuation,\ " "*len(digits + punctuation)))
    return tokens.split(" ")

def normalOrder(recipes, queries): 
    for r in recipes: 
        parts, scores = [[],[],[],[]], 0 
        parts[0] = countTokens(r["title"]) 
        parts[1] = countTokens(r.get("categories", None )) 
        parts[2] = countTokens(r.get("ingredients", None)) 
        parts[3] = countTokens(r.get("directions", None)) 
     for q in queries: 
           scores += 8 * parts[0].count(q) + 4 * parts[1].count(q) + 2 * parts[2].count(q) + 1 * parts[3].count(q) 
      r["score"] = scores + r.get("rating", 0)
    return recipes
```

Comment: the `get` helped me a lot it made it a bit faster but definitely neater. thank you!